# Write to Firebase Firestore denied - Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to save the users who sign in in the firebase database.
this is the function which is used to update the signed in user in the firebase, the fuction uses a uid to create a document with this id :

```
  final Firestore _db = Firestore.instance;

 void upadteUserData(FirebaseUser user) async {
    DocumentReference ref = _db.collection("users").document(user.uid);
    print("in update");
   return ref.setData({
      "uid": user.uid,
      'email': user.email,
      'displayName': user.displayName,
      //'emergency': []
    }, merge: true);
  }
```

and here is the sign in fuction:

```
 Future signInWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      AuthResult result = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
      FirebaseUser user = result.user;
      upadteUserData(user);
      print("signing in");
      print(result.user.email);
      return _userFromFirebaseUser(user);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }
```

here's the console after signing in
[image]
I tried it twice and it was working perfectly fine 3 weeks ago. However, when I try to sign in today with different e-mails, it did not update the fire base. Any idea?

Comment: Looking at the log, you get 'in update' before 'there is a user' implying that you're trying to write to the db before the sign in is complete. I see you defined the functions as ```async``` but you didn't ```await``` the result before continuing. Try adding await to the ```return``` in both instances and see if that helps

Comment: Security rules are rejecting the write.  Please edit the question to show the relevant rules.  Also, on Stack Overflow, please don't use screenshots of text.  Copy the text into the question so it's easier to read and search.

Comment: @doug stevenson: thank you for your reply, can you please tell me how can i access relevant rules?

Comment: Firebase Project Console > Database (left panel) > Rules tab